# best way to secure a streaming flv being output to a player in php?

Tags: php, stream, flv

looking at embedding a flv player into a page but wish to read the flv file from a non www accessible location. I tried to write a controller action which takes a encrypted querystring, decrypt it, then output the contents to the page using readfile() but nothing seems to happen.

I'm not sure if its becuase i'm sending the wrong content-type or that the readfile function is choking on the flv file sizes (40 MB+).

[I'm using something like the following](http://www.pastie.org/588409)

Goint to the above page lets me download the flv fine, just not stream it from the player. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This streams flv and mp3 files perfectly in a few apps I wrote:

```
$mime = ''; // place appropriate mimetype here
$file = 'somefile.flv'; // place your filename here

header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$file'");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
readfile ($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use PHP for streaming, PHP has it's time execution and memory limits (configured at php.ini). 
   1.1. Don't use PHP for providing static content, it's heavy and basically will kill apache performance.
2. When you do use PHP you also need to write seek option (to jump from point to point).
3. It's highly recommmended to use Nginx/Lighttpd for flv streaming via HTTP protocol, or to use Red5/Wowza for flv streaming via RTMP protocol.

My preffered suggestion is to use Nginx with mods:

- [flv](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFlvModule) (for flv streaming).
- [Secure Links](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureLinkModule) (to protect files from hotlink and set TTL for each link).
- [Limit rate after](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#limit_rate) - to save bandwidth.

With secure links you can generate a link for a specific user by IP, and you can set the link TTL for 60 seconds, after that the link is dead and the user will not be able to access the content again.